# Error during sending double value to mySQL server

Tags: java, mysql

I have such error (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.8p1, "description", "test2")' at line 1) during sending double value to mySQL server
How is it possible to solve this problem

`DatabaseFunc.sendDescription(new Description(5,5.0,"description", "test2"),2);`

```
    public static void sendDescription(Description description, int table_id){
        Statement statement = null;
        try{
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            System.out.println(description.getId());
            System.out.println(description.getRate());
            String query = String.format("insert into descriptions (id, rate, description, name) " +
                    "values (%d, %a, \"%s\", \"%s\")", description.getId(), description.getRate(), description.getDesctiption(), description.getName());
            statement.executeUpdate(query);
        }
        catch (SQLException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i smell a locale issue here. floating point values need to be provided with a decimal **point**. make sure that String.format doesn’t format it differently

Comment: Why are you using `%a`?

Comment: Don't use printf formatting, use a ```PreparedStatement```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using %a for formatting the **rate** implying that its a decimal point.  The error is telling you that the value it encountered is **.8p1**.

So, it is likely that this is what your data contains.  It needs to be floating point number.